How to add "Visual Effect" as an active target in a Unity 6 shader graph?
I've just started learning and getting into shader graphs in Unity and I was just watching some tutorials on Youtube and realized that in the video, when he created the shader graph, he could add "Visual Effects" into his Active Targets as shown in the picture below:

However, when I checked mine, it does not give me the Visual Effect option as shown:

I did some research for a bit but I could not pinpoint why. Therefore, I would kindly like to ask for help in answering a few questions.

Is this because I am using a different Unity version? in the video it did not state what version is he using but I am assuming its one of the 2022 versions since the video was posted during that time, and I am using Unity 6 Preview version.
How much does it matter if I were to use different active targets? (eg. Universal Unlit .etc) This is a shader graph for a VFX graph that I am working on.
How can I get the "Visual Effects" option?

Any help is much appreciated, thanks!
I tried with Unity version 2022.3.46f1 and there is a "VFX Shader Graph" option at the menu there. May I know where can I find that in Unity 6.0 preview version?

My guess would be with the added support for Vulkan/Metal... in the pipeline, the fundamental approaches to shaders would have changed.

That option was deprecated in VFX Graph version 12 (comes with Unity 2021.2) in favor of a simple toggle in the Universal target options. From the release notes:

You can now use existing Shader Graphs for both regular Materials and
visual effects. To make this possible, the dedicated Visual Effect
target is now deprecated.

You can leave Universal as an active target in your Shader Graph, and scroll down to enable Support VFX Graph on it. It should now show up in your VFX Graph Output Particle Shader Graph block.
